# VQMod does not appear to be properly generating vqcache files

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I can not use vqmod. When ı click vqmod in admin panel it says

**VQMod does not appear to be properly generating vqcache file**

I use also auto related products xml. caused by this thing? I don't know.

Also some product pages says that

**Notice: Undefined index: product_info in /home/elmaicom/domains/elmacimarketi.com/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php on line 416**

It belongs to:

```
> //related by manufacturer
>                      if(count($results)<3 && (int)$this->data['product_info']['manufacturer_id'] > 0){//change to
> suit number of products to display 
>                      $temp = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelatedByManufacturer($this->data['product_info']['manufacturer_id'],$this->request->get['product_id'],count($results));
> foreach($temp as $t){
>                        if(!empty($t)){                    
>                           $results[] = $t;               
>                            }          
>                       }        
>                   }
```

Help please. I have to use vqmod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that undefined index `product_info` error

In the vqmod (xml file in `vqmod/xml` directory) of your related product extension
replace

`(int)$this->data['product_info']['manufacturer_id']`

with

```
(int)$product_info['manufacturer_id']
```

Comment: I did that but ı'm still get same error. VQMod does not appear to be properly generating vqcache file in vQmanager

Comment: @user3392616 so you need to first solve that problem. my first guess is same as jay said permission issues. you can try re-installing vqmod by going to address `http://yoursite.com/vqmod/install/` , it probably won't solve but you can try it. Also you can try to install it once again by downloading and installing newer (or same) version from here https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/downloads/list

Comment: I installed again and again. ı downloaded again the last version but problem continues

Comment: @user3392616 now that are you not getting that error which means now your vqmod is working good, just that vQmodmanager is not working. `note that vqmodmanger is not required for vqmods to work its just someting to maintain your vqmods`. try reinstalling vqmodmanger,see if it works. if it doesn't work you can use  vqmoderator (http://vqmoderator.com/)

Comment: I cant fix vQmod Manager then I install vqmoderator. I'm using this too now and this enough for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

1. Check whether vqmod is installed by calling https://domain.com/vqmod/install in browser. If not installed, then please scroll up and read the steps.
2. Verify file name and path, also confirm that the code in search tag exists in the file mentioned.
3. Check folder permissions. Make sure that vqmod/vqcache and vqmod/logs have 755 or 777 permission. If nothing works, then try 777 permission recursively for vqmod folder.
4. Check the error logs in vqmod/logs.
5. Check the installed vqmod version and the vqmod version given in xml file (`<vqmver><![CDATA[version]]></vqmver>`), both need to be the same.
6. Delete the files in vqmod/vqcache and check again. Also see whether vqmod copy of your file is generated or not.
7. Move any vqmod xml file outside the vqmod folder and check. If everything works, move the xml back to the vqmod folder. I don’t know the reason, but it worked for me in some cases :) !
8. `<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?` – put this line at the top of the XML to make it valid and more compatible.
9. Try the VQMod Manager extension. It may help you!

Reference link: [Opencart Vqmod tutorial](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

This

Move any vqmod xml file outside the vqmod folder and check. If everything works, move the xml back to the vqmod folder. I don’t know the reason, but it worked for me in some cases :) !

Also worked for me

Answer (score 1):

1. Removing vqmod/mods.cache file.
2. set vqmod/vqcache permission to 777

Comment: this fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

vQmod doesn't have an admin interface, so it's probably a tool like [vQmoderator](http://vqmoderator.com) or [vQmod manager](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2969) you are referring to. In regards to the cache files not generating correctly, this is almost certainly down to file permissions. Make sure your permissions set on `/vqmod/vqcache/` are set to the same as your `/system/cache/` folder

Comment: Yes its vQmod Manager, Also ı had already set permissions to 777 both of cashes. Problem continues.

Comment: @user3392616 try what i suggested in my answer, if it solves your product page problem (or generate some other error) then it can imply vqcache files are generating

Comment: my product page problem solved. ı don't get "Undefined index: product_info" error now. But still ı can not use vQmodmanager.

Answer (score 0):

Never too late: try removing `mods.cache` file.
www-data will regenerate it for you again.
Refresh vQmod Manager on admin panel.
** make sure you set admin user group premissions